# Queries in Dynamo DB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I have a doubt in Dynamo DB.

Let us assume I have a document in Mongo DB
If I have to fetch all the events where studentId = 125, I would query like this in MongoDB,

```
db.getCollection('events').find({"team.participants.student.studentId" : 125});
```

Is it possible to query this same in `AWS DynamoDB`? If yes, how?

I'm able to query through nested maps, but not through List.

```
{
    eventId : 1,
    team: {
        teamId : 9
        participants : [
            {
                participantId : 1,
                student: {
                    studentId : 123,
                    fname : "Jon",
                    lname : "Snow"
                }
            },              
            {
                participantId : 2,
                student: {
                    studentId : 124,
                    fname : "Adam",
                    lname : "Sandler"
                }
            },              
            {
                participantId : 3,
                student: {
                    studentId : 125,
                    fname : "Samuel",
                    lname : "David"
                }
            }               
        ]
    }
}
```